# How can I display the category name in the single post when using WP Blog and Widget?

Tags: categories, widgets

I am using the free version of [WP Blog and Widget](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-blog-and-widgets/) plugin for my blog. It's working perfectly.

My issue is, I have to display the current post category name on my single page. So I tried below code on a single.php page to check the category name.

```
$cat = get_the_category();
print_r($cat);
```

but I am not getting the category name. I am getting an empty array.

```
Array ( )
```

How can I fix this problem?

#### Single.php

```
<?php
    /**
     * The template for displaying all single posts
     *
     * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#single-post
     *
     * @package WordPress
     * @subpackage Twenty_Nineteen
     * @since 1.0.0
     */

    get_header();
?>

<section id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main">

        <?php
            /* Start the Loop */
            while ( have_posts() ) :
                the_post();

            $cats = array();
            foreach (get_the_category($post_id) as $c) {
                $cat = get_category($c);
                array_push($cats, $cat->name);
            }

            if (sizeOf($cats) > 0) {
                $post_categories = implode(', ', $cats);
            } else {
                $post_categories = 'Not Assigned';
            }
            echo $post_categories;


            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content/content', 'single' );

            if ( is_singular( 'attachment' ) ) {
                // Parent post navigation.
                the_post_navigation(
                    array(
                        /* translators: %s: parent post link */
                        'prev_text' => sprintf( __( '<span class="meta-nav">Published in</span><span class="post-title">%s</span>', 'twentynineteen' ), '%title' ),
                    )
                );
            } elseif ( is_singular( 'post' ) ) {
                // Previous/next post navigation.
                the_post_navigation(
                    array(
                        'next_text' => '<span class="meta-nav" aria-hidden="true">' . __( 'Next Post', 'twentynineteen' ) . '</span> ' .
                            '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Next post:', 'twentynineteen' ) . '</span> <br/>' .
                            '<span class="post-title">%title</span>',
                        'prev_text' => '<span class="meta-nav" aria-hidden="true">' . __( 'Previous Post', 'twentynineteen' ) . '</span> ' .
                            '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Previous post:', 'twentynineteen' ) . '</span> <br/>' .
                            '<span class="post-title">%title</span>',
                    )
                );
            }

            // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
            if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) {
                comments_template();
            }

            endwhile; // End of the loop.
        ?>

        </main><!-- #main -->
    </section><!-- #primary -->

<?php
    get_footer();
```

Comment: Where are you displaying the category name? in the post loop or outside the post loop, like widget?

Comment: @AtifAqeel, I have to display the category name on my single.php page.

Comment: `get_the_category()` gets terms from the `category` taxonomy. The plugin that you linked creates a custom post type, so are you sure it's not also creating a separate taxonomy for 'blog categories'? If your post has custom taxonomy terms you need to use [`get_the_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/), not `get_the_category()`.

Comment: @JacobPeattie, Let me try your above comment.

Comment: @NarenVerma Keep in mind that if you use `get_the_terms()` you need to provide the taxonomy name, which I don't know. Check the URL of the edit screen for those categories. It should include the taxonomy name.

Comment: @JacobPeattie, I tried below code 
$term_obj_list = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'taxonomy' );
print_r($term_obj_list);

and I got output  WP_Error Object ( [errors] => Array ( [invalid_taxonomy] => Array ( [0] => Invalid taxonomy. ) ) [error_data] => Array ( ) )

Comment: Read my previous comment.

Comment: @JacobPeattie, Yes, I read your first comment. The plugin which I am using that creating a separate taxonomy for 'blog categories'.

Comment: Read my other comment.

Comment: @JacobPeattie, I got your point taxonomy=blog-category so I have to use like $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'blog-category' );
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
echo $term->name;
}

Comment: Right. Does that work?

Comment: @JacobPeattie, I got my category name. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You can you just simply put this code into your singl.php

```
foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) 
{
    echo $category->cat_name . ' '; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am getting only  Not Assigned

Comment: so you have assign the category?

Comment: Yes, I have category and I already assigned.

Comment: did you put the code inside the while loop?

Comment: Yes, I added  inslide while ( have_posts() ) : Please check my code. I updated in the question.

Comment: okay give me while

Comment: I just added your code inside while loop and rest of th code I got from wordpress theme.

Comment: Your code is working if I deactivate the plugin WP Blog and Widget. But I don't want to deactivate because I have created all the blog in that

Comment: Please explain the down vote reason.

Comment: i have updated my answer and i check this code is working fine inside single.php loop https://prnt.sc/s2rhwd

Comment: who down voted my answer?

Comment: I did, because there's no functional difference between the code in your answer and the original question. It won't solve the problem.

Comment: He did not said that he there is any custom post type? he is getting post from blog. not from the custom post type.

Comment: They are using a custom post type. They linked to the plugin that added it in their question. But that's completely irrelevant because even if they were using the blog your answer is incorrect because it doesn't change anything meaningful about the code.